# BigQuery GROUP_CONCAT drops precision of float numbers

Tags: google-bigquery

I use GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate a list of float numbers, but the results drop the precision and only preseves 4 decimals.
How can I group_concat the number with original precision?

Example, 
GROUP_CONCAT trim the float number 49.2795576 to '49.2796'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be "fixed" if to use BigQuery Standard SQL
(see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) and also [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql))

```
SELECT id, STRING_AGG(CAST(x as STRING)) as y 
FROM (SELECT 1 as id, 49.2795576 as x)
GROUP BY id
```